# All php functions work but phpinfo

Tags: php, apache2.4

I recently upgraded my VPS PHP version to 7.0.3 and everything seems to work fine including `php -v` which shows:

(I know I'm getting some warnings but those shouldn't be anything serious)

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: execute
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: suhosin: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.3 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2016 00:24:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I'm using directadmin and so I created a file `index.php` in the `public_html` and this is its content:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo md5("sometext");

phpinfo();

?>
```

The output is only:

```
a29e90948f4eee52168fab5fa9cfbcf8
```

Why are `md5` and `echo` working but not `phpinfo`???

I'm on Centos and using PHP 7.0.3 with Apache (httpd) 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpinfo() is disabled for free accounts on that particular hosting provider
if youhave access to `php.ini`
Go to the `php.ini` and remove `phpinfo` from

```
disable_functions =...,phpinfo,....
```

save and restart webserver

Comment: I said I have a VPS!

Comment: Also this line doesn't exist on `php.ini` or at least I couldn't find it using `nano`

Comment: `/etc/.php.ini.swp
/etc/php.ini
/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Comment: try this `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Comment: OK, I found that and removed `phpinfo` from it now will restart webserver.